# Getting next payday date

Tags: java, android

I've got a problem in which I'm asking for a next payday date, which is the nearest working weekday to that date. For example if the user selects that their next payday is on the 25/03/2017, their actual payday might be on the 24/03/2017 as the saturday isn't a working day.

I've had a scoop around and can only find methods such as Calendar.add which I can use to add 4 weeks onto the current payday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) and then use a `LocalDate` object. You can check if the day is a saturday or sunday and then add or subtract 1 day. Check the documentation for detailed information.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, I was contemplating writing out a custom method of doing something like this, but I knew something more tested and reliable would exist somewhere. Thank you.